# Any fun 'Chat with an Expert' sessions from April Fool's?

Tags: discussion

It was pretty funny on Meta SO watching all the new questions.

Anyone on music have a fun exchange with the 'Expert'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had one encounter with "Adviza".

http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/SCWLql4H60ad

It stemmed from a question about playing scales on the guitar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pry a secret of him, but he was pretty tight-lipped.

http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/aaqGVoswEux1

> Expert: It takes a lot of resources to provoke me into a confession about my encounter with eliza by the wheat tree. Just sayin'.

Comment: I should confess that [I was fooled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174504/167924) the first time, at first.

Comment: I was only fooled for a minute. As soon as I saw the name "Adviza", I realized that it was based on the ancient mainframe computer program "Eliza", which I played around with many, many years ago.

Comment: I didn't notice the name. That would've tipped me off.

Comment: The program source for Eliza is in many-a 70's LISP textbook. But none from this pile next to me right now.